# .htaccess refinements to rewrite rule which hides .php extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, filenames

Last month I used the rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

to make my site URLs nicer and to chop off the .php from URLs.

I have found some problems with the above code, it works fine for what it was intended and for nothing else, as I have an issue; for subfolders, such as

```
www.site.co.uk/horses/
```

the .htaccess generates a 'file not found' for

```
www.site.co.uk/horses/.php
```

as it adds a .php onto an empty string.

Comment: You could have simply added a second `RewriteCond` which checks whether it’s not a directory …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent quite some time reading the same examples over and over again about how to use Mod_rewrite but the examples missed what I was looking for, which was to prevent an empty 'not-defined' filename having .php appended to it. 
Examples and answers are great but they did mostly hang on the same premise that the reason for mod_rewrite was to turn folder shapes /page/content/variable/variable into GET requests (I generalise).

My solution to the problem of www.site.co.uk/horses/ not finding the index.php file is thus: 
(*follow symlinks is on already...*)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.|/]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Adding an "if ending of the file is not . OR / " to the rule. I know it's simple Perl Regex but I figure this may be useful to others out there with similar problems.

As an additional, I've not seen any examples of it but can an .htaccess have multiple conditions, and/or multiple Rule lines?

Also, how come this issues does not appear for the base/root directory, as the address www.site.co.uk/ always works, regardless of the rewrite rules?

Comment: If this solved your issue, you can mark your own questions as answers. This makes it clear to people having the same issue in future. Thanks for posting how you solved it tho!

Comment: It won't let me mark it as solved for 2 days! I clicked the "answer your own question" when posting.